# Binding to Observable Environment array values

Tags: swiftui

My sample is just keeping a list of string replacements I want to perform, when I use this as a @State variable it works great:

```
@Observable class StringReplacement: Identifiable {
    var old: String
    var new: String
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    
    init() {
        self.old = ""
        self.new = ""
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var stringReplacements: [StringReplacement] = [
        StringReplacement()
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($stringReplacements) { replacement in
                HStack {
                    TextField(
                        "Old",
                        text: replacement.old
                    )
                    Text("->")
                    TextField(
                        "New",
                        text: replacement.new
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I want to move `stringReplacements` to an Observable Environment class, I get errors:

```
@Observable class AppManager {
    var stringReplacements: [StringReplacement] = [
        StringReplacement()
    ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(AppManager.self) private var appManager

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(appManager.stringReplacements) { replacement in
                HStack {
                    TextField(
                        "Old",
                        text: replacement.old //ERROR Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'
                    )
                    Text("->")
                    TextField(
                        "New",
                        text: replacement.new
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Binding` is for value types and `Bindable` is for `Observable`.

Change your first set of code to

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var stringReplacements: [StringReplacement] = [
        StringReplacement()
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(stringReplacements) { replacement in
                @Bindable var replacement = replacement
                HStack {
                    TextField(
                        "Old",
                        text: $replacement.old
                    )
                    Text("->")
                    TextField(
                        "New",
                        text: $replacement.new
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your second code will convert seamlessly

```
@Environment(AppManager.self) private var appManager

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(appManager.stringReplacements) { replacement in

               @Bindable var replacement = replacement
```