# SwiftData save on dismiss

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm trying to implement SwiftData to my code, but the name is not saving. When adding a new item and I dismiss the page, the item stays persisted but if I change the name it won't save it.
That's the code for the View:

`struct EinkaufslisteDetailView: View {`

```
@Environment (\.modelContext) var context

@ObservedObject var vm: EinkaufViewModel
@State private var isDone: Bool = false
@State private var anzahl: Int = 5
@State private var textFieldText: String = ""

@Query var items2: [Einkauf]

let kategorieName: String

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
                List {
                   ForEach(items2) { item in
                        EinkaufItemRowView(name: item.name, anzahl: item.anzahl, isDone: isDone, textFieldText: textFieldText)
                        .padding(.vertical)
                    }
                   .onDelete { indexSet in
                       for index in indexSet {
                           context.delete(items2[index])
                       }
                   }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
        .navigationBarItems(
            trailing: Button(action: { vm.addItem(context: context) },
                                label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            })
            /*.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                EinkaufAddView(vm: vm)
                    .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.7)])
            }*/
        )
        .navigationTitle(kategorieName)
    }
}
```

}

`#Preview {`
`EinkaufslisteDetailView(vm: EinkaufViewModel(), kategorieName: "Testname") }`

`struct EinkaufItemRowView: View {`

```
@State var name: String
@State var anzahl: Int
@State var isDone: Bool
@State var textFieldText: String

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: isDone ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "checkmark.circle")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            .foregroundStyle(isDone ? .green : .primary)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .onTapGesture {
                isDone.toggle()
            }
        
        TextField(name, text: $textFieldText)
            .strikethrough(isDone ? true : false)
            .font(.title2)
        
        Spacer()
        
            Button(action: {
                //guard item.anzahl <= 1 else { return }
                anzahl -= 1
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            })
        
            Button(action: {
                anzahl += 1
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            })
        
        Text("\(anzahl)")
            .frame(width: 40)
            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
            .font(.title2)
            .bold()
        
    }
}
```

}

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
class EinkaufViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var items: [Einkauf] = []

@Published var kategorien: [Kategorie] = [
    Kategorie(title: "Obst", titleColor: Color.yellow),
    Kategorie(title: "Fleisch", titleColor: Color.purple),
    Kategorie(title: "Milchprodukte", titleColor: Color.blue),
    Kategorie(title: "Getränke", titleColor: Color.green)
]

@Published var fleischArray: [String] = ["Huhn", "Schwein"]

func addItem(context: ModelContext) {
    let newItem = Einkauf(name: "Neuer Artikel", anzahl: 0)
    context.insert(newItem)
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?
Btw, sorry if the code is hard to read or not good written, I'm currently learning swift...

Comment: State is a source of truth with no connection to its parent. Use Bindable and then Binding. Something very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77675493/binding-to-observable-environment-array-values/77675545#77675545

Comment: Where to use Bindable and where Binding? I was thinking that State was the problem, but I was not sure how or where to change it to bindable.

Comment: Replace the State in the RowView with Binding, as far as Bindable look at the link it will go in the ForEach. Look at the link it is very similar.

Comment: Also something that is very important State, should always be marked private.

Comment: I don't quite get it yet... if I change the ForEach like in the link you send, I get this error: Cannot reference invalid declaration 'item'
That's the new foreach
ForEach(items2) { item in
                           @Bindable var newName = item
                           EinkaufItemRowView(name: newName, anzahl: item.anzahl, isDone: isDone, textFieldText: textFieldText)
                            .padding(.vertical)
                        }

Comment: Look closer… Bindable is for the item you’ll use $item.name for the Binding

Comment: Ahh i See, i forgot the $Binding symbol... but the error is still not going away.. maybe I am an idiot haha but if I add the $-sign to the "EinkaufItemRowView(name: $newName,...) it changes nothing..

Comment: Why have you not removed the view model yet like everyone said in your last question?

Comment: Because I didnt understand why to remove it and I wanted to learn to use mvvm